# Redirect to a page in a modal

Tags: 8

I have follow this tutorial to make a modal:
http://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/loading-and-rendering-modal-forms-drupal-8

But when the submitModalFormAjax method is called I want redirect the user to a specific page:

```
/**
 * AJAX callback handler that displays any errors or a success message.
 */
public function submitModalFormAjax(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $response = new AjaxResponse();

  // If there are any form errors, re-display the form.
  if ($form_state->hasAnyErrors()) {
    $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('#modal_example_form', $form));
  }
  else {
    // <<<--- redirect to homepage
    // $response->addCommand(new OpenModalDialogCommand("Success!", 'The modal form has been submitted.', ['width' => 800]));
  }

  return $response;
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You tried the RedirectCommand? https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Ajax%21RedirectCommand.php/class/RedirectCommand/8.2.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 * AJAX callback handler that displays any errors or a success message.
 */
public function submitModalFormAjax(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $response = new AjaxResponse();

  // If there are any form errors, re-display the form.
  if ($form_state->hasAnyErrors()) {
    $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('#modal_example_form', $form));
  }
  else {
    $response->addCommand(new RedirectCommand(Url::fromRoute('<front>')->toString());
    // $response->addCommand(new OpenModalDialogCommand("Success!", 'The modal form has been submitted.', ['width' => 800]));
  }

  return $response;
}
```